# python re module - What regular expression to use to extract pieces of text

Tags: python, regex

I have text which shows course numbers, names, grade and other information for courses taken by students. Specifically, the lines look like these:

```
0301 453  20071 LINEAR SYSTEMS I                    A    4   4    16.0

0301 481  20071 ELECTRONICS I WITH LAB              A    4   4    16.0

0301 481  20084 ELECTRONICS II WITH LAB      RE     B    4   4    12.0

0301 713  20091 SOLID STATE PHYSICS          NG          0   0     0.0

0511 454  20074 INT'L TRADE & FINANCE               B    4   4    12.0
```

I want to write a regular expression that extracts:

```
LINEAR SYSTEMS I
ELECTRONICS I WITH LAB
ELECTRONICS II WITH LAB
SOLID STATE PHYSICS
INT'L TRADE & FINANCE
```

I wrote the following

`pattCourseName = re.compile(r'([-/&A-Z\':\s]{2,})(\s+[A-Z])')`

However, this gives me

```
LINEAR SYSTEMS I
ELECTRONICS I WITH LAB
ELECTRONICS II WITH LAB      RE
SOLID STATE PHYSICS
INT'L TRADE & FINANCE
```

That is, I cannot get rid of the RE part.

Can someone please help with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the layout is fixed as you show, then forget the regular expression, and just grab the columns you want:

```
course_name = line[16:45].strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in open("file"):
    s=filter(None,line.split(" ",4))
    print s[3].replace("  ","|").split("|",1)[0]
```

output

```
$ python myscript.py
LINEAR SYSTEMS I
ELECTRONICS I WITH LAB
ELECTRONICS II WITH LAB
SOLID STATE PHYSICS
INT'L TRADE & FINANCE
```

Comment: Beautiful! This will be great when the columns do not align and I learnt new commands from your solution. Thanks!